# Concatanate Lists in one DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following lists:

`rBruta = [76843339.93, 68564200.34, 114946898.37, 75687842.36, 34530505.68, 116481217.14, 95696528.10000002, 40015273.68, 33416618.4, 34530505.68, 33416618.4, 81118744.08]`

`rLiquida = [417648532.25, 362509251.24, 410746539.59, 365572296.03, 335338029.26, 416780171.86, 423577376.06, 385353312.36, 380507243.23, 404170649.16, 380269620.17, 426637510.38`

`rEmpres = [1169415.89, 1015025.9, 1150090.31, 1023602.43, 938946.48, 1166984.48, 1186016.65, 1078989.27, 1065420.28, 1131677.82, 1064754.94, 1194585.03`

And i need to concatenate those 3 lists into 1 single DataFrame. Like stacking one in another.

I tried to transform each on into a dataframe Column, then, used the T for transpose the columns.
Worked, but i have 16 lists to concatenate with different names.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([rBruta,rLiquida,rEmpres])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should do the work

```
df = pd.DataFrame([rBruta, rLiquida, ... all lists], columns = ["a1", "a2", ... "a12"])
# as you have 12 columns in your data
```